# Find the minimum possible value of PC+PD.

Tags: geometry

From [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwQGA.png), $AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular to $AB$, $AC=102$, $BD=201$, $AB=404$, where $P$ is a point on the line segment $AB$.

How can I find the minimum possible value of $PC+PD$?

---

I have tried the following way.

Assume $AP=x$ and $BP = 404-x$.

Based on the [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dmqf.png), I form this equation:
$$102x+201(404-x)=201(404)-99x$$

This resulted in infinite solutions where I get $0=0$.

Based on Pythagoras Theorem, I formed a function to find the minimum value for $x$.

$$\begin{align}
PC^2+PD^2&=[102^2+x^2]+[201^2+(404-x)^2]\\
f(x)&=2x^2-808x+214021
\end{align}$$

Since this is a quadratic function, I find the minimum value for $x$ using the formula for axis of symmetry.
$$\begin{align}
min. x&=-{b\over 2a}\\
& =-{(-808)\over 2(2)}\\
& =202
\end{align}$$

Then, I substitute $x=202$,
$$\begin{align}
 PC+PD&=\sqrt{101^2+x^2}+\sqrt{201^2+(404-x)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{101^2+202^2}+\sqrt{201^2+(404-202)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{51208}+\sqrt{81205}\\
& =511.3
\end{align}$$

---

I would like to know if my answer is correct as well as knowing your solutions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution finds the $x$ that minimises $PC^2+PD^2$, which will not be the same as the value that minimises $PC+PD$. Instead, reflect $D$ in line $AB$ to get $D'$. Then minimising $PC+PD$ is the same as minimising $PC + PD'$, which will be achieved by making $CPD'$ a straight line. Then Pythagoras's Theorem gives the minimum value as $\sqrt{404^2+(102+201)^2} =505$.